# How could I remove backtracking from this code?

Tags: prolog, clpfd

The goal is to select shapes that don't touch each other using constraints (clpfd). Calling `start(Pairs,4)` would return `Pairs = [1,3,5,7]`.

One problem I noticed is that if I print Final before labeling, it prints `[1,3,5,7]`. Which means labeling isn't doing anything.

What could I change/add to this code in order to fix that and also remove possible backtracking?

[image]

```
:-use_module(library(clpfd)).
:-use_module(library(lists)).


% init initialises Pairs and Max
% Pairs - The elements inside the Nth list in Pairs, 
% represent the index of the shapes that shape N can touch 

init([[3,5,6,7],[4,5,7],[1,4,5,7],[2,3,7],[1,2,3,7],[1],[1,2,3,4,5]],7).

start(Final, N):-
  init(Pairs, Max),

  length(Final, N),
  domain(Final, 1, Max),

  ascending(Final),
  all_different(Final),
  rules(Pairs,Final),

  labeling([],Final).

rules(_,[]).
rules(Pairs,[H|T]):-
  nth1(H,Pairs,PairH),
  secondrule(PairH,T),
  rules(Pairs,T).

secondrule(_, []).
secondrule(PairH, [H|T]):-
  element(_,PairH,H),
  secondrule(PairH, T).

ascending([_|[]]).
ascending([H|[T1|T2]]):-
  H #< T1,
  ascending([T1|T2]).
```

Answer (score 3):

This is an Independent Set problem, which is an NP-hard problem. Therefore, it is unlikely that anybody will ever find a way to do it without search (backtracking) for general instances.

Regarding your code, `labeling/2` does nothing, because your `rules/2` is in fact a search procedure that returns the solution it it can find it. `all_different/1` is useless too, because it is implied by `ascending/1`.

Presumably, your goal is a program that sets up constraints (without any search) and then searches for a solution with `labeling/2`. For that, you need to rethink your constraint model. Read up a bit on independent sets.